# mod_fcgid process graceful kill fail sending sigkill and page not loading

Tags: apache-2.2, 500-error, fcgi

Today I experience the following:
Pages are not loading (error 500) and in log I see this:

mod_fcgid process graceful kill fail sending sigkill and page not loading

How can I solve this? What might cause it?